# Android JAVA : Convert org.json.JSONArray to java.lang.String[]

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I am working an Android app where when synchronising the date from server, data is received as json string, which is being first converted into JSONObject using
`JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("jsonStringFromServer")` and this `jsonObject` has a bunch of `key:value` sets, where `value` is in the form of `JSONArray`, like
`{"id1":["stringa1","stringa2","stringa3"], "id2":["stringb1","stringb2","stringb3"], "id3":["stringc1","stringc2","stringc3"]}` etc

I need convert this `JSONArray` into a simple `String[]`, and when I tried casting using simple `(String[]) jsonObject.get("id1")`, I get this error **java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]**

I looked around, but have not been able to find a simple solution similar to how a ArrayList can be converted into String[] in java. Any will he highly appreciated

Comment: please share code.

Comment: Thanks @The_Humble_Fool, that means first create an ArrayList<> from JSONArray (as I would not know it's length) and then create String[] from this ArrayList<>? As there is a large amount of data, I was hoping to find some straight forward method and minimize the time taken.

I also had thought of using ObjectSerializer to serialize the Array at server side first (original data is in String[] form) and then desrialize inside Android.

Any comment on which would be better approach?

Comment: @AlwaysaLearner https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray#length()

It has a length method which you can call when constructing the array. This would help you get the size right and push items into it. No need for additional ArrayList creation then.

Comment: @AlwaysaLearner I'm not an expert in that area. What I'd suggest if to implement pagination and get data in batches and when requested by user for next batch. That will help ease up things for client. You can cache data on client side as new data keeps coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JsonArray is not same as a Java's array. You cannot convert a JsonArray to regular Java arrays by casting. What you can do is, extract objects from the JsonArray into a regular Java array by iterating over JsonArray.

Comment: This along with your comment worked great for me...

Answer (score 1):

You can use streams to collect data from json array, modify the code as per your needs. The code below should give you an overview.

```
List<String> values = IntStream.range(0, jsonArray.length())
                .mapToObj(i -> array.getJSONObject(i).get("key").toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks but I found this a little confusing and could not get this working. A simple iteration using JSONArray length was the way I went...